# What is the best method to convert the String into Array of object. with specific pattern?

Tags: javascript, lodash

I have an array of string in which some HTML code is used. e.g

```
["An ultrasound-guided biopsy was performed for the <code>[1.4 cm solid]</code> mass located in the [right ]breast, at the [12:00] position.  This was described on the previous[ Ultrasound and mammography reports.]  The skin was prepped in the usual manner.  Local anesthetic was administered to the access site.  [A guiding needle was inserted initially.]  Subsequently, a [14] gauge biopsy needle was placed adjacent to the abnormality under ultrasound guidance.  Once the needle was documented to be in the correct location, [4 ]core specimens were obtained using a [Bard automated firing device.]  A metallic clip was inserted into the breast at the location of the biopsy.  A bandage was applied to the access site.  Post procedure mammographic imaging was done.  The specimens were sent to the laboratory for pathological analysis.&nbsp;&nbsp;","\n","Complications: <code>[none]</code>","\n<p></p>\n"]
```

I want to split the string on the base some pattern and want this result

```
 [{
    "text": "An ultrasound-guided biopsy was performed for the"
}, {
    "text": "1.4 cm solid"
    "value":"code"  
},{
  "text":"mass located in the [right ]breast, at the [12:00] posit… to the laboratory for pathological analysis.&nbsp;&nbsp"
}]
```

Comment: Can you assume no nested `<code>` tags?

Comment: On what basis do you want it  to be split....Like where do you want the array to be split

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might find [the `DOMParser`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMParser) useful.

```js
const arr = ["An ultrasound-guided biopsy was performed for the <code>[1.4 cm solid]</code> mass located in the [right ]breast, at the [12:00] position.  This was described on the previous[ Ultrasound and mammography reports.]  The skin was prepped in the usual manner.  Local anesthetic was administered to the access site.  [A guiding needle was inserted initially.]  Subsequently, a [14] gauge biopsy needle was placed adjacent to the abnormality under ultrasound guidance.  Once the needle was documented to be in the correct location, [4 ]core specimens were obtained using a [Bard automated firing device.]  A metallic clip was inserted into the breast at the location of the biopsy.  A bandage was applied to the access site.  Post procedure mammographic imaging was done.  The specimens were sent to the laboratory for pathological analysis.&nbsp;&nbsp;","\n","Complications: <code>[none]</code>","\n<p></p>\n"];

var domparser = new DOMParser();

// Parse the string in the array to a new HTML document
const parsed = domparser.parseFromString(arr[0], 'text/html');

// Iterate over the child nodes with reduce to produce a new array of objects
const obj = [...parsed.body.childNodes].reduce((acc, node) => {

  // Destructure the relevant props from each node
  const { nodeType, textContent, tagName } = node;

  // Trim the edge spaces from the text
  const text = textContent.trim();

  // If the nodeType is 3 (text node) return an object with
  // just the text
  if (nodeType === 3) return acc.concat({ text });

  // Otherwise get the value
  const value = tagName.toLowerCase();

  // Do further string replacement
  const replacedText = text.replace(/[\[\]]/g, '');

  // Return the object with the text and the value
  return acc.concat({ text: replacedText, value });
}, []);

console.log(obj);
```

Futher reading

- [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)
- [Destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment)